# Create something like an oval using css

Tags: css, shapes, clip-path

Please tell me, is it possible to create a similar shape/mask using css? I tried using clip-path and border radius, but I didn’t get a similar shape.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkFEI.png)

I found a way to make such a shape filled with color - https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/#aa-tv-screen-shape

But since it uses ::before, I can't use it as a mask for the image. I would be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a border-radius: 70px; or just increase the size of the pixel if your element is way too big. You should target that specific element you want to be oval and put the border-radius and it's done. Hope I help.